# List in JScrollPane painting outside the viewport

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a list, each item of which has several things in it, including a `JProgressBar` which can be updated a lot. Each time one of the items updates its `JProgressBar`, the `ListDataListener` on the list tries to scroll it to the visible range using

```
/*
 * This makes the updating content item automatically scroll
 * into view if it is off the viewport.
 */
public void contentsChanged(final ListDataEvent evt) {
    if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
        /**
          * Make sure the scrolling happens in the graphics "dispatch" thread.
          */
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run()  {
               contentsChanged(evt);
            }
        });
    }
    if (playbackInProgress) {
        int index = evt.getIndex0();
        currentContentList.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);
    }
}
```

Note that I'm trying to make sure the scrolling is done in the dispatch thread, since I thought maybe the problem was it being scrolled while it was repainting.  And yet, I still have a problem where if things are really active, some of the list items paint outside of the viewport, overwriting what's outside the `JScrollPane`.  Forcing an exposure event will repaint those things, but it's annoying.

Is there anything else I need to look out for to stop these things painting outside of their clipping area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly enabling double-buffering on the JList and/or the components that it is drawing over? (with:[`setDoubleBuffered(boolean aFlag)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setDoubleBuffered(boolean)))

Another thought is that you *might* need to exit the function immediately after delegating to the EDT.  The way your code is written, it looks like the update will happen in both threads if `ContentChanged` is invoked from a non-EDT thread.  Logging in the first `if` (or set a breakpoint in the if -- but *not* in the runnable -- should help determine if that is your problem.

eg:

```
public void contentsChanged(final ListDataEvent evt)
{
    if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread())
    {
        log.debug("Delegating contentsChanged(...) to EDT");

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                contentsChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        // don't run ensureIndexIsVisible twice:
        return;
     }

     if (playbackInProgress)
     {
         int index = evt.getIndex0();
         currentContentList.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);
     }
}
```